# Disable div onclick when I click on button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div id="question" onclick="location.href='{% url 'read_question' question.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
        <p>my text</p>
    </button>
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

When I click on the div `#question` I go to an other page.
But when I click on the button I also go to the other page.
However my button is *disabled*...

I would like not to go to another page when I click on the button.

In **Firefox** when I click on the button nothing happens (This what I want).

But in **Chrome** I go to the other page...

Someone could help me to *permanently disable* the button?

I use HTML5 and Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button ***is*** disabled and that works exactly as it should (prevents the default action of the button).

However, by default, `click` events are bubbling. Which effectively means any such event on any elements in your page does not only get triggered on that particular element, but on every one of its parents until `document` or until one of the elements in the chain stop the bubbling.

To stop a `click` event (or any other bubbling event) from bubbling you have to call [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method on it.

In your case:

```
document.querySelector('#question btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

...or, in jQuery:

```
$('#question btn').on('click', e => { e.stopPropagation() });
```

Now your button will not pass the click event to the div. If it's enabled it will do what you want it to, if not, it won't. The `<div>` won't have a clue in either case.

If you only want to cancel the bubbling when the button is disabled, change the selector from `#question btn` to `#question btn[disabled]`

Answer (score 0):

you have the button inside the div so when you click on the button you are also clicking on the div.  You can also do it your way and just check to see if the event.taget is a button.  if it is don't go to the url, if it isn't then go.

```html
<div id="question" onclick="location.href='{% url 'read_question' question.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer;">xxx
    
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
        <p>my text</p>
    </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `onclick` to the `<button>` itself rather than the surrounding `<div>`. The `disabled` attribute of the button will not be able to disable the `onclick` applied to its parent element.

In the two examples below I have styled it so you can see the difference between the surrounding `div` (In blue) and the `button`. Notice that the alert will only fire in the top example when clicking the div.

I am assuming that your styling means you can not see the difference between the div and button and it is left for Chrome and Firefox to decide whether you are clicking the disabled button or the div.

```css
div {
background: blue;
padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<div onclick="alert('test')">
    <button disabled>my text</button>
</div>
```

```css
div {
background: blue;
padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button disabled onclick="alert('test')">my text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){

console.log(event.target.innerHTML);

if(event.target.innerHTML=='div')window.location.href='{% url ' + 'read_question' + 'question.id %}';



}
```

```html
<div id="question" onclick='myFunction()' style="cursor:pointer;">
<button class="btn btn-primary" >div</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
        <p>my text</p>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the button in the div, you should use `event.stopPropagation();`. Try the following code.

```
    <body>
    <div id="question" onclick="goLink();" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="noLink(event);">
            <p>my text</p>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
    function goLink(){
     window.location.assign("{% url 'read_question' question.id %}");
    }
    function noLink(){
     window.alert("I didn't go anywhere.");
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

There is also a `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` method. I hope this helps you out.